# Adding a Folder with Client Side Object Model using Custom Content Type

Tags: content-type, csom, library

I need code for adding a folder with ***Client Side Object Model*** using Custom Content Type (Folder) on SharePoint Library.

Answer (score 0):

This script will add folder to any library:

```
   var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            var folder = list.RootFolder;
            ctx.Load(folder);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            folder = folder.Folders.Add(folderName);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: It will add Folder, not custom content type of type folder.

Comment: 1: That was quick; 2: Ok he want to add content type to the folder, I'll update my answer

Comment: No, I understand he wants to add custom content type that inherits from Folder content type - but it may be the same as adding just a normal CT.